# Найти количество разных чисел в массиве

Tags: java

Имеется:

`Map<String, ?> allEntries = sPrefFavorites.getAll();`

```
private List<Integer> listOfCategory= new ArrayList<>();
```

Как через

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
          String[] splited = entry.getValue().toString().trim().split("-");
          listOfCategory.add(Integer.parseInt(splited[1]));
}
```

Подсчитать количество разных splited[1]?

(entry вида 54-**21**-1, 54-**10**-15, 54-**3**-5).
 split нужен для поиска различий в записях по второму числу.
List создал как вариант. Если есть другой вариант и он лучше - то вообще здорово.

Для примера в скобках выше, правильное количество должно быть равно 3 (21, 10 и 3 - разные числа).

Для примера 54-**2**-1, 54-**3**-5, 54-**2**-9, 54-**3**-8 - правильный ответ 2 (2 и 3 - разные числа).

Comment: Например, добавлять числа как ключи в Map.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Попробую - отпишусь.

Comment: А что, множеств в этой вашей Джаве нету?

Comment: @VadimTukaev множества? set'ы, что ли? Я не понимаю русский. [http://habrahabr.ru/post/237043/][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/237043/

Comment: @argamidon: Это очень плохо. Я про русский. А то, что в Джаве такая развесистая иерархия коллекций, только усиливает мое недоумение: а зачем же тогда использовать Map? Пихаем числа в HashSet (или как он там у Вас называется), а потом просто смотрим на его длину...

Comment: @VadimTukaev нормальный набор коллекций у нас. Привыкнуть надо. А ещё есть набор многопоточных вариантов коллекций, количество которых в пару раз больше чем количество классических. А ещё всякие Apache Common Collections (правда я ниразу их не использовал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
        string input;
        while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = input.Split('-');
            if (parts.Length != 3) { break; }
            set.Add(parts[1]);
        }
        foreach (string s in set)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: хех, вопрос про Яву, а ответа на каком языке? :) Я, конечно, вижу, что синтаксисы ну очень похожи, но что это? си-шарп? :-)

Comment: Да. Я в комментах написал, что надо использовать множества, а потом решил проиллюстрировать. Согласитесь, тут главное - принцип. Даже Пайтон для этого подошел бы. Синтаксис - дело второстепенное...